# Rewriting ends up with not loading js / css

Tags: apache, .htaccess

With the following .htaccess file, I obviously, get alot of 404's on loading scripts and css because the browser keeps looking in the wrong directory.

I am a newb at htaccess and have no clue about how to fix it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^$ client/app/index\.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Dir structure is as follows:

project /client / app / index.html

.htaccess is located in project directory.

Comment: where are your js and css files stored? Or how do you call your css and js files in the index.html?

Comment: This can be solved by a adding a **<base href="/client/app">** in head part of your webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you that redirect users with a 301 to correct path. This will end with your problems.

```
RewriteRule ^$ client/app/index\.html [L, 301]
```

If you are worried about seo look at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

All of the calls at your server are being redirected to your `RewriteRule`. Add a `RewriteCond` (RewriteCondition) to ignore CSS and JS files, if they exist:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ client/app/index\.html [L]
```

Explanation:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

If the requested filename exists (`css/main.css`), do not go through with the RewriteRules.

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]`

If the file does not exist, but matches one of the extensions, do nothing. This is helpful because you get a 404 if `css/main-2.css` does not exist, rather than redirecting you to `index.php`.

And then finally is your own rule, which redirects all non-conditioned rules.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file, this is what worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [R=301]
```

Thank you!